# using encodePacked vs encodeWithSignature when call function on an external contract

Tags: abi, calldata

When we call a function on an external contract, we need to put calldata as an argument.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

contract test1 {

    mapping (address => uint256) public _count;
    function countNum(address sender) public {
        _count[sender] ++; 
    }

}

contract test2 {
    function call(address _address,bytes memory data) public {
        _address.call(data);
    }

    function getdata1(bytes memory data,address from) public view returns(bytes memory) {
        return abi.encodePacked(data,from);
    }

    function getdata2(address _spender) public pure returns(bytes memory) {
        return abi.encodeWithSignature("countNum(address)", _spender);
    }
}
```

I called *countNum()* of contract test1 from *call()* in contract test2.

The code inside *getdata1()* and *getdata2()* uses different abi.
*getdata1()* use encodePacked, *getdata2()* use encodeWithSignature. The return values ​​of the two functions are different.

However, when both result values ​​are put in *call()* , Both successfully called the countNum() function.

The two data are different values, why were both able to succeed?

.. and Thank you so much for attaching the link to the related content...

Comment: What the input are you passing to `getdata1` as `data`?

Comment: input getdata2() return data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both data succeed because one only appends some dirty bytes at the end.

This is the returned value of `getdata2`:

```
0x7f02eb76000000000000000000000000abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabca
```

where `0x7f02eb76` is the selector and `abc..ca` is the spender address.

When you calculate `getdata1` using the previous value as input you just end up adding the `from` address at the end:

```
0x7f02eb76000000000000000000000000abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcadefdef...efd
```

with `def...efd` the address.

When you call `test1.countNum`, the function will read only the first address as argument, it doesn't care that the data has extra bytes.